# How to ensure NetworkStream to send data immediately without closing the Stream or TcpClient?

Tags: c#, tcpclient

I have a very simple code snippet that tries to send data via `TcpClient` and its associated `NetworkStream`.

```
var client = new TcpClient("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", 1234);
NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str);
stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

I've found that usually the data won't be sent immediately after `stream.Write()`. If I add `client.Close()` or `stream.Close()` then data will be sent. However, in my case, I'm trying to wait for the server to send some ACK message back so I want to reuse the original `NetworkStream` without closing either the `TcpClient` or `NetworkStream`. How can this be done?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: What I mean is the socket will attempt to send the data stream immediately, without considering network latencies.

Comment: Define "immediately". It is true that for smaller writes to the stream, the Nagle algorithm will delay transmission _briefly_ (much less than a second), and it's true you can turn that off if you want to. But in practice the delay is less of a problem than the inefficiency introduced by disabling it. It's _strongly_ recommend that you not disable it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set [`TcpClient.NoDelay`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.nodelay(v=vs.110).aspx) to `true` so that [Nagle's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm) isn't used.

From the MSDN Library documentation:

> When NoDelay is `false`, a TcpClient does not send a packet over the network until it has collected a significant amount of outgoing data. Because of the amount of overhead in a TCP segment, sending small amounts of data is inefficient. However, situations do exist where you need to send very small amounts of data or expect immediate responses from each packet you send. Your decision should weigh the relative importance of network efficiency versus application requirements.

Comment: Note that the documentation is not precisely correct: "TcpClient does not send a packet over the network until it has collected a significant amount of outgoing data". It will delay transmission only briefly (~500 ms, depending on implementation). If after that period, the amount of data still is not "significant", the data _will_ be sent. Nagle does not cause lengthy delays in transmission, and generally one should not disable it, because it provides important benefits. **At the very least, one ought to fully understand the original question before proposing this solution.**

Comment: @Peter: Wikipedia says (without any citation): "In general, since Nagle's algorithm is only a defense against careless applications, it will not benefit a carefully written application that takes proper care of buffering; the algorithm has either no effect, or negative effect on the application."

Comment: I disagree with that claim. There's no reason an application should have to do its own buffering, and doing so accomplishes nothing. It still has to wait for new data, and still has to be able to go ahead and send under-sized packets if too much time passes without there being enough. I.e. that's just reinventing the wheel. Indeed, if one does disable it, then one _had better_ make they one's own code is buffering correctly, otherwise inefficient use of network bandwidth is practically assured.