# C# bytes only sent at the end of code... [Sockets]

Tags: c#, sockets, send, exit

I am new to C#, it is my first code :D I was codding in Java in the past and now I have a lot of troubles with sending sockets.
When I try to send a socket, it is only send at the total end of the code:
for example

```
    using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Program
    {
        public static TcpClient client;
        public static NetworkStream networkStream;

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            client = new TcpClient("62.210.130.212", 35025);
            networkStream = client.GetStream();
            byte[] usernameBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("This is just a test bro!");
            networkStream.Write(usernameBytes, 0, usernameBytes.Length);
            networkStream.Flush();

            while (true)
            {
                // Infinte loop
            }
            // THE SOCKER WILL ONLY BE SENT HERE, AT THE END OF THE CODE, WHY ?!
        }
    }
}
```

Here the socket will only be sent when shutting down the programm (because of the wile loop)

and here

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Program
    {
        public static TcpClient client;
        public static NetworkStream networkStream;

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            client = new TcpClient("62.210.130.212", 35025);
            networkStream = client.GetStream();
            byte[] usernameBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("This is just a test bro!");
            networkStream.Write(usernameBytes, 0, usernameBytes.Length);
            networkStream.Flush();
        }
    }
}
```

And in this case it will be sent directly because it is the end of the code...

Does anyone know why this happens and how to fix it ? I want my sockets to be sent at any time of the running time, not just at the end :D

Thank you very much ! Thank you for reading this question until there.
  Julien.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does anyone know why this happens and how to fix it? I want my sockets to be sent at any time of the running time, not just at the end.

## Why is this happening?

Due to [Nagle's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm), the transmission will be delayed briefly (in the milliseconds).

Which means your code does not offer enough time before it goes to the loop.

```
networkStream.Write(usernameBytes, 0, usernameBytes.Length);
networkStream.Flush();

// the time between here is not enough for nagle's algorithm to complete

while (true) { } // blocks the thread from doing any more work

// so, it will end up sending here instead.
```

---

## How to fix it?

#### A Quick Solution - Disable Nagle's Algorithm

As documented in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27412388/3645638) you could set `TcpClient.NoDelay` to `true` to disable Nagle's algorithm.

You can accomplish that easily by adding it to your code:

```
 client = new TcpClient("62.210.130.212", 35025);
 client.NoDelay = true; // add this line of code to disable Nagle's algorithm
```

*Note: This solution will in force an immediate send. However, as your question wasn't clear the on the exact requirement, please note that this is probably not the "best" solution.*

#### A Better Solution - Force execution by disposing your resource(s)

If you dispose/close your `TcpClient` it will accomplish the same thing. In addition, it will provide the added (and much better practice) of disposing the resource immediately when you're done using it.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient("62.210.130.212", 35025))
    using (NetworkStream networkStream = client.GetStream())
    {
        byte[] usernameBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("This is just a test bro!");
        networkStream.Write(usernameBytes, 0, usernameBytes.Length);
    }

    while (true) { } // loop infinitely
}
```

*Note: This doesn't actually send the packet immediately like the solution above, but instead forces the packet to send because we are closing it. However, the result in your case is the same effect and this is a much better approach that you should practice.*

---

### What is Nagle's Algorithm?

The Nagle algorithm is designed to reduce network traffic by causing the socket to buffer small packets and then combine and send them in one packet under certain circumstances.

A TCP packet consists of 40 bytes of header plus the data being sent. When small packets of data are sent with TCP, the overhead resulting from the TCP header can become a significant part of the network traffic.On heavily loaded networks, the congestion resulting from this overhead can result in lost datagrams and retransmissions, as well as excessive propagation time caused by congestion. The Nagle algorithm inhibits the sending of new TCP segmentswhen new outgoing data arrives from the user if any previouslytransmitted data on the connection remains unacknowledged.

The majority of network applications should use the Nagle algorithm.

Setting this property on a User Datagram Protocol (UDP) socket will have no effect.

Comment: Oh, thank you really much, It works fine now, I just have another problem.

Comment: Now how to recieve and send new lines with the networkStream inside the while ? I cant create another instance of it...

Comment: Yes, I have to wait 90 minutes until posting a new question so i will link it when it's done. Thank you really much for helping me :D

Comment: @NoBravesStudio - You should read this to get you going quickly https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w89fhyex(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44226506/socket-sending-and-recieving-in-c-sharp-while-loop