# Socket Sending and Recieving in C# (while loop)

Tags: c#, sockets, line, send

Here is my code. I am codding a simple Socket test.

```
    using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Connexion au serveur 62.210.130.212");
            using (client = new TcpClient("62.210.130.212", 35025))
            using (NetworkStream networkStream = client.GetStream())
            {
                byte[] usernameBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(username);
                networkStream.Write(usernameBytes, 0, usernameBytes.Length);
            }

            while (true)
            {
                Byte[] data = new Byte[256];
                Int32 bytes = networkStream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                String responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
                Console.WriteLine("recieved: " + responseData);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that i can't use the networkStram anymore in my code because it has been deleted on the end of the using tab.

Can someone help me with that problem, I am new to C#, this doesn't exist in Java.

Thank you!
  Julien.

Comment: Your code makes no sense - what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You should put your 'while' loop into the 'using' block. Objects that you create in the definition of 'using' block dispose right after exiting from it.

Comment: Nope, else the send won't be exectued... It's the following of that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44226506/socket-sending-and-recieving-in-c-sharp-while-loop

Comment: What i want is simple but wtf i doesn't work... It is to send a line and then recieve multiple lines in a while.

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to extend the using over *all* usages of the object you're using - this makes sense, if you just look at the word: All the code inside the curled brackets is *using* the object inside the brackets. So this should at least solve that specific problem:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Connexion au serveur 62.210.130.212");
            using (client = new TcpClient("62.210.130.212", 35025))
            using (NetworkStream networkStream = client.GetStream())
            {
                byte[] usernameBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(username);
                networkStream.Write(usernameBytes, 0, usernameBytes.Length);

                while (true)
                {
                    Byte[] data = new Byte[256];
                    Int32 bytes = networkStream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                    String responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
                    Console.WriteLine("recieved: " + responseData);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! but as I said, I tryied that but doesn't work the line is only sent after the while loop...

Comment: The seconde line of the using is executed at the end of the while loop...