# How to stop NetworkStream from buffering TCP packets

Tags: c#, tcp, network-programming, networkstream

I want to send TCP Packets to a server. However I'm having an issue where multiple `.Write()`s are buffered together to create one bigger packet, despite the [MSDN documentation saying that they are not buffered](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.autoflush?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-7.0#System_IO_StreamWriter_AutoFlush).

> The Flush method implements the Stream.Flush method; however, because NetworkStream is not buffered, it has no effect on network streams.

I'm currently sending packets like this:

```cs
void TestFunction(NetworkStream stream)
{
  var array = new byte[] { 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x8e, 0x00 };
  stream.Write(array);

  array = new byte[] { 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00 };
  stream.Write(array);

  
  array = new byte[] { 0x0a, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x24, 0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x66, 0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x66, 0x00 }:
  stream.Write(array);
}
```

Investigating the traffic via Wireshark shows me that they're all one big packet though, instead of 3 packets:

```cs
char peer1_2[] = { /* Packet 9 */
0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x1e, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x73, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0a, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x74, 0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x66, 0x61, 0x73, 
0x64, 0x66, 0x00 };
```

I did try putting a `.Flush()` after each `.Write()`, but that didn't change anything either.

Is there anything I missed? Do I need to use Sockets directly to achieve that functionality? I've quickly looked at their documentation + how NetworkStream's Write is implemented, but couldn't find anything that would point me towards a solution.

Comment: See this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.sendbuffersize?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-7.0#System_Net_Sockets_TcpClient_SendBufferSize

Comment: [How to ensure NetworkStream to send data immediately without closing the Stream or TcpClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27412291/how-to-ensure-networkstream-to-send-data-immediately-without-closing-the-stream) may help.

Comment: @SoftwareDveloper Unfortunately, that didn't seem to change anything. I've tried setting the `SendBufferSize` property to both very small values (power of 2's between 4 and 128) as well as larger values (8192\*2, -\*4, -\*10), but the packets stayed the exact same. It seems actually that the buffer size isn't changing at all after a quick console log. Setting the property of the Stream's socket also doesn't have any effect. And while setting the Stream's socket (EDIT: or tcpClients) `NoDelay` to `true` does *somewhat* help, it's still splitting them up (just 2 packets instead of 3)

Comment: TCP will send in as many packets as necessary. A single `Send` doesn't necessarily result in a single `Receive` at the other end, it's just a stream of bytes. Instead you need a framing mechanism see also https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html